# How Can I insert System.out.println() in Eclipse with ctrl + space

Tags: java, eclipse

When i was watching a video about java, a man has inserted `System.out.println()` immediately to screen. How can i do it. He only Write "S" character...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

i do it this way: write `syso` and press `ctrl+space`. i believe you can configure this stuff: `window -> preferences -> java -> editor -> content assist`

Answer (score 6):

`Syso` and hit  <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SPACE</kbd> it will work in eclipse ....

And  if you want to change it,,,

> window > Preferences > Java > Editor > Templates.

Comment: Thanks a lot. i tried it but, i wrote it with dot(.) so it was a problem :)

Comment: i was writing it likes System.o and then Ctrl + Space

Comment: FYI, this is a Java Editor Template, which can be customized in **Preferences** > **Java** > **Editor** > **Templates**.

Answer (score 3):

Type `syso` and press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.

---

There is **no need** to press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>. You can bring up content assist whenever you type a letter:

1. Navigate to `Window > Preferences > Java > Editor > Content Assist`.
2. Enter `.abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz` into the field entitled *Auto activation triggers for Java*.

Now, whenever you type, the code completion suggestions will appear.

Answer (score 1):

Type `Syso`, then press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

This will have a problem if your window 7 have more than one language input selection. because `CTRL + SPACE` will trigger the language change instead of insert `System.out.println()`;

Answer (score 1):

Actually I found out you don't even have to write `syso`, in eclipse even 

`yso` + <kbd>Ctrl+Space</kbd>
 is enough.

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse Neon it's `sysout` <kbd>Ctrl+Space</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

The shortcut for syso CTRL+spacebar works in all version of eclipse's instead setting should not be changed if setting's problem has been changed  so you can
make it proper by performing following steps 
1)Change the binding of the shortcut 
2)Made sure it was checked under templates
3)Autocompletion on

Comment: It's not really clear what you are saying and we already have several answers with the same content.

Answer (score 0):

I like using the template box `Ctrl+Alt+Space`, this way you can quickly

1. Select and highlight what to print
2. `Ctrl+Alt+Space`
3. type : `syso`
4. Enter

Answer (score 0):

So if you are a mac user, type sysout and try control+space, with control key i mean the one beside fn key in a mac keypad.

Answer (score 0):

For me it started working after I checked `Template Proposals` in `Eclipse` -> `Preferences` -> `Java` -> `Editor` -> `Content Assist`. I switched it on in both the `default` and `cycling` sections.