# How get ctrl + space to autocomplete in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, macos, preferences, populate, system.out

"System.out.print " does not autocomplete when I press ctrl + space. It shows it in the box and I have to click it for it to populate. I am using a Mac and coding in eclipse. I searched the keyboard preferences but no luck.

Comment: Maybe you were lucky to keep your macOS up to date, but not lucky to keep your Eclipse up to date. If that's not the case, share more details of your unlucky experience and the things you have so we can tell you why you're the only one who isn't lucky.

Comment: It shouldn't require anything further if it's the only proposal, by default, but you should also be able to press Enter or Space on the keyboard to insert it. Do those not work?

Answer (score 0):

It works by default, i just type `sysout` and then hit `Ctrl+Space`, and it auto-completes `System.out.println()`.

I think you should check once, go to Window->Preferences->General->Keys, and scroll down till you find the Content Assist, like in the image.
[image]

If still there's a problem and you are unable to get the auto-complete for `sysout`, then go to Window->Preferences->Java->Editor->Content Assist . From there , you can configure the shortcuts.

For reference, you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10190268/how-can-i-insert-system-out-println-in-eclipse-with-ctrl-space/49005656)